Add google analytics tag manually after wordpress update
I am trying to add the google analytics tag manually to my wordpress website but the wordpress portal seems to have changed since the available instructions for this were written. The instructions I have found say to edit the theme header by accessing the header.php file. My wordpress allows me to go to theme editor, then design, and access patterns and header. The resulting header code looks different to what I was expecting and it is not obvious where the google tag should go. Can anyone help?

How are you accessing your header.php file?
While Google (and basically every other script developer on earth) always tell you to add their script to the <head> you don't ACTUALLY have to do that.  I just stick it Google Analytics at the bottom of pages and it always works.  Regardless, let us know how you're accessing the code/header.php and show us what you're working with.

I am not sure I am accessing the header.php file. I am just clicking on theme editor-> patterns -> Template Parts -> header. The code doesn't look as I would expect if it were header.php. I tried just pasting the google analytics code in the file but then you can see the text on the website as opposed to it being hidden. I need it to be on every page so putting it in the header.php did make sense. It seems like direct access of that isn't possible anymore.

If you're doing it through the block editor then chances are that WP is sanitizing and stripping it out. You're not supposed to paste scripts into the block editor.  Why wouldn't access to your files be possible anymore?  This is why it's hard to answer questions when there's no code snippets provided.  What sort of access do you have to your site?  FTP/SFTP, the file editor under the Appearance tab?  Or just the GUI in WordPress?
